# Creating Service Agreement for a Macro with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create an SLA for a macro.
For example, I have created a functionality with help of Excel VBA.
Macro gets executed whenever trying to execute within 6 months.
If we try to execute that macro after 6 months it should not work, rather it should ask for renewal or so.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, something like this may be of use:

- add a database
- read something from it
- if the value is not read, give a nasty msgbox and close the workbook w/o saving
- write in the db the date first time the user uses the VBA tool
- check if there are 6 months after this date
- if there are 6 months -> ask for renual with a nasty msgbox and close the workbook w/o saving